# Postfix, dovecot . emails work when ssh'ed into server, but cannot connect to thunderbird

Tags: postfix, dovecot, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on digital ocean with Ubuntu 18. I have followed the following [Github](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/emailwiz) [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zP7qooM4pY&t=679s&ab_channel=LukeSmith) tutorial to get email server up and running .
The problem is however when i am logged into the server i can send and receive emails using mutt. But when i try to connect it to thunderbird it gives me error "Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account ". I have tried it both auto and manual ways with these [settings](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/emailwiz/blob/master/README.md#logging-in-from-thunderbird-or-mutt-and-others-remotely)

I am not very expert at doing this. It is my first time for handling such activity. The only change i made is commented out this [line](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/emailwiz/blob/0bdbbbef6d5fbdb9b6283b8601fcdcb346af5820/emailwiz.sh#L130) as i had no such file in (/usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem). Please help me resolve this issue.

i am using the same postfix and dovecot settings as provided in [this](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/emailwiz/blob/master/emailwiz.sh) link. some mail.log is given below i believe it's when i try to connect to the server via thunderbird.

```
Oct  1 15:41:19 mail postfix/smtpd[16024]: connect from unknown[121.178.116.27]
Oct  1 15:41:19 mail postfix/smtpd[16025]: connect from unknown[121.178.116.27]
Oct  1 15:41:19 mail postfix/smtpd[16024]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[121.178.116.27]: QUIT\r\n
Oct  1 15:41:19 mail postfix/smtpd[16024]: disconnect from unknown[121.178.116.27] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Oct  1 15:41:19 mail postfix/smtpd[16025]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[121.178.116.27]: QUIT\r\n
Oct  1 15:41:19 mail postfix/smtpd[16025]: disconnect from unknown[121.178.116.27] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Oct  1 15:43:26 mail postfix/smtpd[16108]: connect from unknown[141.98.10.136]
Oct  1 15:43:26 mail postfix/smtpd[16108]: disconnect from unknown[141.98.10.136] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Oct  1 15:44:59 mail postfix/smtpd[16108]: connect from unknown[45.249.91.180]
```

Answer (score 0):

update: Had to ufw allow 587 and 993 to make it work...